# Accessing Fields from Deleted and Inserted Tables in Trigger

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trFoodUpdate ON Food
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    DECLARE @Action nvarchar(1000) = 'Change(s): '

    IF Inserted.FoodID <> Deleted.FoodID THEN SET @Action += CHAR(13) + '-You have updated FoodID from ' + Inserted.FoodID + 'to ' + Deleted.FoodID
    .... --Other IF-s--


    INSERT INTO FoodTriggerTable (FoodID, FoodName, FoodDesc, FoodPrice, Action, InsertActionTime)
    SELECT FoodID, FoodName, FoodDesc, FoodPrice, @Action, GETDATE() FROM Inserted
GO
```

I'm trying to insert the updated `FoodID`, `FoodName`, etc. to my `FoodTriggerTable`. However, I can't seem to do:

`IF Inserted.FoodID <> Deleted.FoodID THEN ...`

It says that 'The multi-part identifier "Inserted.FoodID" could not be bound'. The same error occurs on `Deleted.FoodID`. Why is that so?

I figured I could use `DECLARE` to declare temporary variables which can store all the needed data from said tables, but can I use the approach above?

**EDIT**

I seem to have misunderstood many concepts in SQL Server, but I'm trying to insert the updated `FoodID`, `FoodName` and the rest of the fields to a table called `FoodTriggerTable`, which stores 'logs' that contain information in regard to an update of a record.

I'm trying to insert a sentence that lists the change(s) made to a record in my `Food` table inside my `FoodTriggerTable`. Thus, I tried setting a new variable called `@Action` to store a string that I will then concatenate with other string(s). The string which is contained by `@Action` will then be inserted in the `Action` field of `FoodTriggerTable` using:

```
INSERT INTO FoodTriggerTable (FoodID, FoodName, FoodDesc, FoodPrice, Action, InsertActionTime)
SELECT FoodID, FoodName, FoodDesc, FoodPrice, @Action, GETDATE() FROM Inserted
```

Suppose I updated only the price of a food in `Food` table, I'd like my `Action` field in `FoodTriggerTable` to contain the following string:

`Change(s): You've changed the food price from 30 to 45`

So what I'm trying to do is to concatenate `'You've changed the food price from' + previous food price + 'to' + after update food price`.

Comment: Inserted and Deleted are tables. You need to select or join them. And be careful....the pattern you have here indicates that you think there will only ever be a single row in those tables which is not correct. Triggers in sql server fire once per operation, and triggers need to handle sets of data.

Comment: And your if statement is nowhere close to working. IF is used to control flow of statements. I don't really understand what you are trying to accomplish here so not sure how to help steer you back on the right path.

Comment: FYI, allowing your ID to change guarantees a break in the history that is not easy to track.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm sorry for this perhaps poor-quality question, but I've updated some things and I hope that it clears things up.

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean How do I disallow the change of my ID?

Comment: To be honest I would not want to store all the extra data here. "You've changed the food price from" has no business being in the table. It would be the same on every row until you decide you want to change the text. This kind of thing belongs in the tool that displays the changes. Consider how difficult it will be to produce a report of changes over time that includes things like "what the percentage of change on FoodX over the last 2 years". You would have to parse all the extra stored text.

Comment: You really should store only the FoodID, FoodPrice and ChangeDate. You don't need to store anything else. The "new" price will be either in the next change row or the main table. No need to store it repeatedly.

Comment: @SeanLange I see, thank you! So is it correct to say that I can keep track of the price changes of a food throughout a period of time just by looking at the records of FoodTriggerTable that occur on the same food (by checking FoodID)?

Comment: Yes!!! That is exactly what I am suggesting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182877/discussion-between-wealthy-player-and-sean-lange).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a full working example of one way to tackle this sort of thing. It tracks changes across all the columns. I created the Food and FoodAudit tables in addition to a sample trigger. Then I created some data and updated it a few times so you can see how this might work.

```
create table Food
(
    FoodID int identity
    , FoodName varchar(100) not null
    , FoodDesc varchar(100) not null
    , FoodPrice decimal(7,2) not null
)

create table FoodAudit
(
    FoodID int not null
    , FoodName varchar(100) not null
    , FoodDesc varchar(100) not null
    , FoodPrice decimal(7,2) not null
    , ChangeDate datetime not null
        CONSTRAINT DF_FoodAudit_ChangeDate DEFAULT getdate()
)

GO

create trigger TR_Food on Food after UPDATE as

    set nocount on;

    insert FoodAudit
    (
        FoodID
        , FoodName
        , FoodDesc
        , FoodPrice
        , ChangeDate
    )
    select d.FoodID
        , d.FoodName
        , d.FoodDesc
        , d.FoodPrice
        , getdate()
    from deleted d

GO

insert Food
(
    FoodName
    , FoodDesc
    , FoodPrice
)
select 'Bacon'
    , 'Yummy'
    , 3.42

GO

update Food
set FoodPrice = 1.23
where FoodName = 'Bacon'

waitfor delay '00:00:02' --used to simulate updates at different times.

update Food
set FoodPrice = 12.23
    , FoodDesc = 'wow'
where FoodName = 'Bacon'

waitfor delay '00:00:02' --used to simulate updates at different times.

update Food
set FoodPrice = 12.23
    , FoodDesc = 'wait'
where FoodName = 'Bacon'

waitfor delay '00:00:02' --used to simulate updates at different times.

update Food
set FoodDesc = 'Yummers'
where FoodName = 'Bacon'

waitfor delay '00:00:02' --used to simulate updates at different times.

select * from FoodAudit
```

Comment: Wow, right, that didn't cross my mind. Instead of taking the updated data, I take the before-update data so that I can store the very first original data in my audit table and also the last update of my data in Food table, right? Thanks! This was what I was trying to achieve, albeit my way of thinking failed miserably.

Comment: Right, the audit table stores the history or changes. The main table contain only the current values. Don't get stuck storing that string you were thinking of. Store the data and leave the pretty sentences to the front end.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still very new to SQL and the obvious reasons of why I shouldn't do something may not seem apparent to me. Thank you once again, have a good day.

Answer (score 2):

Sean's comments already point out the basic misunderstanding evidenced by your code.

To be technical and specific, the reason you get the `The multi-part identifier "Inserted.FoodID" could not be bound` error is because you did not include either `Inserted` or `Deleted` in a FROM clause.

It's not possible to be 100% sure from your broken code, but probably what you need to look into doing is computing the `Action` column in your final INSERT query in your code using a CASE expression so that each row is handled individually.

Comment: I'm sorry for this poor-quality question, but I've added the reasoning behind my code and I hope that it may help you help me figuring these things out.